# How to improve this code, transforming string

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am currently working on a project where I need to convert string in specific way. So, the idea is that string like this:

`r[10,55]r` will be converted to `(Math.floor(Math.random() * (55 - 10 + 1)) + 10)` - making it js value that is random from 10 to 55 (including).

and string like this: `%[50;w]%` will be be converted to `(canvas.width / 100 * 50)` - making it 50% of canvas width (w; stands for width, h; stands for height).

You can also combine these two 'functions' like this: `%[r[0,50]r;h]%` making it `(canvas.height / 100 * (Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 0 + 1)) + 0))`, meaning you will get from 0% to 50% of canvas height.

So, they way I'm doing it right now looks like this:

```
    transform = function(i){
    var i = i;
    while(i.indexOf('r[') > -1){
        var part1 = i.substring(i.indexOf('r['));
        var part2 = i.substring(i.indexOf(']r') + 2);
        var r = part1.substring(0,part1.length - part2.length);

        var partBefore = i.substring(0,i.indexOf('r['));

        var firstNumber = r.substring(r.indexOf('r[') + 2);
        var comma = r.substring(r.indexOf(','));
        var secondNumber = r.substring(r.indexOf(',') + 1);
        firstNumber = firstNumber.substring(0,r.length - comma.length - 2);
        secondNumber = secondNumber.substring(0,secondNumber.length - 2);

        while(firstNumber.indexOf('%[') > -1){
            var part1A = firstNumber.substring(firstNumber.indexOf('%['));
            var part2A = firstNumber.substring(firstNumber.indexOf(']%') + 2);
            var p = part1A.substring(0,part1A.length - part2A.length);

            var partBeforeA = firstNumber.substring(0,firstNumber.indexOf('%['));

            var firstNumberA = p.substring(p.indexOf('%[') + 2);
            var commaA = p.substring(p.indexOf(';'));
            var secondNumberA = p.substring(p.indexOf(';') + 1);
            firstNumberA = firstNumberA.substring(0,p.length - commaA.length - 2);
            secondNumberA = secondNumberA.substring(0,secondNumberA.length - 2);

            if(secondNumberA == 'w'){ secondNumberA = 'canvas.width'; }
            else if(secondNumberA == 'h'){ secondNumberA = 'canvas.height'; }

            var partAfterA = firstNumber.substring(firstNumber.indexOf('%[') + p.length,firstNumber.length);
            firstNumber = partBeforeA + '(' + secondNumberA + ' / 100 * ' + firstNumberA + ')' + partAfterA;
        }

        var partAfter = i.substring(i.indexOf('r[') + r.length,i.length);
        i = partBefore + '(Math.floor(Math.random() * (' + secondNumber + ' - ' + firstNumber + ' + 1)) + ' + firstNumber + ')' + partAfter;
    }
    while(i.indexOf('%[') > -1){
        var part1 = i.substring(i.indexOf('%['));
        var part2 = i.substring(i.indexOf(']%') + 2);
        var p = part1.substring(0,part1.length - part2.length);

        var partBefore = i.substring(0,i.indexOf('%['));

        var firstNumber = p.substring(p.indexOf('%[') + 2);
        var comma = p.substring(p.indexOf(';'));
        var secondNumber = p.substring(p.indexOf(';') + 1);
        firstNumber = firstNumber.substring(0,p.length - comma.length - 2);
        secondNumber = secondNumber.substring(0,secondNumber.length - 2);

        if(secondNumber == 'w'){ secondNumber = 'canvas.width'; }
        else if(secondNumber == 'h'){ secondNumber = 'canvas.height'; }

        while(firstNumber.indexOf('r[') > -1){
            var part1A = firstNumber.substring(firstNumber.indexOf('r['));
            var part2A = firstNumber.substring(firstNumber.indexOf(']r') + 2);
            var r = part1A.substring(0,part1A.length - part2A.length);

            var partBeforeA = firstNumber.substring(0,firstNumber.indexOf('r['));

            var firstNumberA = r.substring(r.indexOf('r[') + 2);
            var commaA = r.substring(r.indexOf(','));
            var secondNumberA = r.substring(r.indexOf(',') + 1);
            firstNumberA = firstNumberA.substring(0,r.length - commaA.length - 2);
            secondNumberA = secondNumberA.substring(0,secondNumberA.length - 2);


            var partAfterA = firstNumber.substring(firstNumber.indexOf('r[') + r.length,firstNumber.length);
            firstNumber = partBeforeA + '(Math.floor(Math.random() * (' + secondNumberA + ' - ' + firstNumberA + ' + 1)) + ' + firstNumberA + ')' + partAfterA;
        }

        var partAfter = i.substring(i.indexOf('%[') + p.length,i.length);
        i = partBefore + '(' + secondNumber + ' / 100 * ' + firstNumber + ')' + partAfter;
    }
    return i;
};
```

and it has some problems..

I don't know how to identify where the `,` ends so I'm using `;` in the `%[...;...]%` function instead, but that's not really a good solution, because I want to add more functions like these in the future. And I can't think of a new 'divider' every time like `, ; . :` obviously.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: `var i = i;` ? what does that do?

Comment: That's the string you put in to get the converted string.. transform("r[1,2]r"); sorry for not including that, i is a bit dumb name for it :)

Comment: Using regexes would help you a lot here. Also, can you combine functions the other way? So like `r[%[50;w]%, w]r`

Comment: If it's working you can try asking on Code Review Stack Exchange.

Comment: ok, so what's the point of ` + 0`

Comment: Yes you can combine functions the other way too. The index of random number function is: r[min,max]r. So if you wanted to get random number from 50% of canvas' width to 100% you would type something like this r[%[50;w]%,%[100;w]%]r

Comment: @I wrestled a bear once - The code is generated, so it doesn't know that it's unnecessary to add + 0

Comment: @user202729 it is kind of 'working' but not really. I still need to figure out how to know where does the ',' begin and end

Comment: You seem to have a context-free language (supporting arbitrary levels of recursion), which are notoriously difficult to pull apart with regex.  You might want to look into a context free language parser.

Answer (score 0):

As chrisz mentions in the comments regular expressions can help out a lot. Here's how you might approach the first two (uncombined) strings using template literals to produce the output from the matched elements.

```js
const regex1 = /r\[(\d+),(\d+)\]r/;
const str = 'r[10,55]r';
const match = str.match(regex1).slice(-2);
const out = `(Math.floor(Math.random() * (${match[1]} - ${match[0]} + 1)) + ${match[0]})`;
console.log(out);

const regex2 = /%\[(\d+);(h|w)\]%/;
const str2 = '%[50;w]%';
const match2 = str2.match(regex2).slice(-2);
const out2 = `(canvas${match[1] === 'h' ? '.height' : '.width'} / 100 * ${match2[0]})`;
console.log(out2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let conversion = 'r[10,55]r'
let reg = /r\[([0-9]{0,3}),([0-9]{0,3})]r/
let format = (string, match1, match2) => {
 return `(Math.floor(Math.random() * (${match2} - ${match1} + 1)) + ${match2})`
}
let res = conversion.replace(reg, format)

console.log(res)
```

```js
let conversion = '%[50;w]%'
let reg = /%\[([0-9]{0,3});([a-z])]%/
let format = (string, match1, match2) => {
let dimension = match2 === 'w' ? 'width' : 'height'
  return `(canvas.${dimension} / 100 * ${match1})`
}
let res = conversion.replace(reg, format)

console.log(res)
```

Here is my work around the two individual scenarios, currently working on a combined conversion scenario.